# How to prove this limit's equality?

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)$=$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(1/x)$.

I think that it could be solved with a variable change but I don't know how can I change te infitity to 0+.

Comment: The obvious change would be $x\to \frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: You are actually supposed proving the change of variables is valid.  You must use the definition of limits to prove this.   Get start by assuming $\lim_{x\to 0^+}  f(x)=L.$    Then use the definition of the limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to \infty$  to prove it must also be $L.$

Comment: I have notice that x $\to $ 0 is equivalent to 1/x $\to \infty$.I think that it may help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This looks obvious but it does need a sound proof. Before giving a formal $\epsilon, \delta$ type argument it is always better to have an informal argument and one also needs to understand that rigor is different from formalism.

So let us assume that $f(x) \to L$ as $x \to 0^{+}$. Now as $x \to 0^{+}$ we can see that $y = 1/x \to \infty$. And rewording it we see that as $y \to \infty$ we have $x = 1/y \to 0^{+}$ and hence $f(1/y) \to L$ as $y \to \infty$. Since the name of the variable is immaterial when calculating limits we can as well write $f(1/x) \to L$ as $x \to \infty$.

This can be easily translated into formal $\epsilon, \delta$ type argument. The statement $f(x) \to L$ as $x \to 0^{+}$ implies that for any $\epsilon > 0$ we have a number $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < x < \delta$.

We need to show that $f(1/x) \to L$ as $x \to \infty$. This would require us to show that corresponding to any $\epsilon > 0$ we must be able to find a number $N > 0$ such that $|f(1/x) - L| < \epsilon$ whenever $x > N$. To find $N$ we first choose a $\delta > 0$ corresponding to $\epsilon$ such that $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < x < \delta$. Let $N = 1/\delta$ so that $N > 0$. Now consider a new variable $y$ such that $y > N$. This means that $0 < 1/y < \delta$ and hence $|f(1/y) - L| < \epsilon$. This shows that $f(1/y) \to L$ as $y \to \infty$ or changing the variable name $f(1/x) \to L$ as $x \to \infty$.